# Prove that if $A ∩ C ⊆ B$ and $a \in C$ then $a \not \in A\setminus B$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Suppose $A ∩ C ⊆ B$ and $a \in C$. Prove that $a \not \in A\setminus  B$.

Need to prove that $a \in C \implies a \notin A\setminus B$

$$\tag1 A ∩ C ⊆ B$$
$$\tag2 (a \in A \land a \in C) \implies a \in B$$
$$\tag3 \lnot(a \in A \land a \in C) \lor a \in B$$
$$\tag4 (a \notin A \lor a \notin C) \lor a \in B$$
$$\tag5 a \notin C\lor (a \notin A \lor a \in B)$$
$$\tag6 a \notin C\lor \lnot(a \in A \land a \notin B)$$
$$\tag7 a \in C \implies a \notin A\setminus B$$

$(1) \implies (2) \implies (3) \implies (4) \implies (5) \implies (6)  \implies (7) $

Is it accurate?

Comment: The steps seem correct. But it might also be simpler to do it less formally. If $a \in A$ then $a \in A \cap C$, so by hypothesis $a \in B$. Hence we can't have both $a \in A$ and $a \not\in B$

Comment: @leibnewtz Consider turning your comment into an answer! You are correct on both counts.

Answer (score 1):

Intersect $A ∩ C ⊆ B$
on both sides by X\B, where X is that universal set thing
to get
$A \setminus B ∩ C = A ∩ C \setminus B ⊆ \emptyset.$
Proof is now immediate.